# Horizontal scroll showing in responsive grid using Angular Flex Layout

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am following the next tutorial about creating responsive grids with Angular Flex Layout:
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/create-a-responsive-card-grid-in-angular-using-flex-layout-3d1b58411e7a

I have finished with this code:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="content" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm="33%" *ngFor="let num of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4" >
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Mountains {{num}}</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="./../assets/images/mountains.jpg">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Himalayas is a mountain range in Asia.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.content > mat-card {
  width: 200px;
}
```

**app.component.ts** has nothing special

**The problem** is that while the creator of the post finished with a shiny flawless responsive grid, mine generates a horrible horizontal scroll:
[image: horizontal scroll]

It shows everytime no matter the size of the window

I have checked and it seems that when I add the "grid" part to: `fxLayoutGap="16px grid"`the div is assigned a negative right and bottom margin.

**What I have tried:**

If I disable the margins, the scroll disappears but the grid is not centered anymore.

I have added to the divs and mat-card the css `overflow:hidden` but it does not work anywhere.

I have tried adding `max-width: 100vw;` to the "content" class and it works, but only until I change the size of the windows.

**Do you know what could I have done wrong?**